# Java regex predefined character class nested inside character class

Tags: java, regex, subtraction

I need to use a regular expression that contains all the \b characters except the dot, .

Something like `[\b&&[^.]]`

For example, in the following test string:

`"somewhere deep down in some org.argouml.swingext classes and"`

I want `org.argouml.swingext` string to match but `org.argouml` string not too match. (Using the [`Matcher.find()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) method)

If I use: `\b(package_name)>\b` they both match, which is not what I want.

If I use: `\b(package_name)[\b&&[^\.]]` I get a [`PatternSyntaxException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/PatternSyntaxException.html)

If I use: `\b(package_name)(\b&&[^\.])` nothing matches.

I use [this link](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/RegexTester/regex-tester.html) to test my regexes.

Context: I have a list of package names from a project and I have to search them inside some texts. Obviously if a nested package is found, I don't want the outer package to match as well, as seen from the above example.

I am not using the `\s` character class at the end because the package may be at the end of line, or it may followed by other nonword characters such as `:` , `)` etc, characters that are contained in the `\b` class. I just want to subtract the . from the \b class.

If anybody knows how to do this, I would be very grateful :)
Thanks

Comment: "all the `\b` characters" - `\b` is not a character. It's a zero-width word boundary anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A negative lookahead would work here:

```
\borg.argouml(?!\.)\b
```

Remember that in Java string literals the backslashes in regular expressions must be escaped:

```
"\\borg.argouml(?!\\.)\\b"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use:

```
\b\w+(\.\w+)+\b
```

FYI, the `PatternSyntaxException` pops up because `\b` matches a position, not a character. A character class always matches 1 character so putting `\b` (a word boundary) inside a character class will cause the exception to be thrown.